# How to select flat structure of two level model in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a two level structure model in MongoDB, like below:

```
export class ProductTypeModel {
    _id: ObjectID;
    name: string;
    children: {
        _id: ObjectID,
        name: string,
        icon: string
    }[];
}
```

It represents the product types in my application. Actually the `children` has almost the same properties with base model, except it has an extra `icon` property.

Now I have data like this:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b9378d9a842a7557223ebfa"), 
    "name" : "Clothes", 
    "children" : [ { 
        "_id" : ObjectId("5b9378d9a842a7557223ebf6"), 
        "name" : "Men", 
        "icon": "xxx"
    }, { 
        "_id" : ObjectId("5b9378d9a842a7557223ebf7"), 
        "name" : "Women", 
        "icon": "xxx"
    }, { 
        "_id" : ObjectId("5b9378d9a842a7557223ebf8"), 
        "name" : "Shoes", 
        "icon": "xxx"
    }, { 
        "_id" : ObjectId("5b9378d9a842a7557223ebf9"), 
        "name" : "Underwear", 
        "icon": "xxx"
    } ] 
}
```

I want them to be selected as:

```
[
    { "_id" : ObjectId("5b9378d9a842a7557223ebfa"), "name" : "Clothes", "parent": null  },
    { "_id" : ObjectId("5b9378d9a842a7557223ebf6"), "name" : "Men", "icon": "xxx", "parent": ObjectId("5b9378d9a842a7557223ebfa") }, 
    { "_id" : ObjectId("5b9378d9a842a7557223ebf7"), "name" : "Women", "icon": "xxx", "parent": ObjectId("5b9378d9a842a7557223ebfa") }, 
    { "_id" : ObjectId("5b9378d9a842a7557223ebf8"), "name" : "Shoes", "icon": "xxx", "parent": ObjectId("5b9378d9a842a7557223ebfa") }, 
    { "_id" : ObjectId("5b9378d9a842a7557223ebf9"), "name" : "Underwear", "icon": "xxx", "parent": ObjectId("5b9378d9a842a7557223ebfa") }
]
```

Is it possible to do this in one query in MongoDB?

I tried `$unwind` but it still contains two level structure in results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try below aggregation

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$project": {
    "data": {
      "$map": {
        "input": { "$concatArrays": ["$children", [{ "_id": "$_id", "name": "$name" }]] },
        "in": {
          "_id": "$$this._id",
          "icon": "$$this.icon",
          "name": "$$this.name",
          "parent": { "$cond": [{ "$eq": ["$$this.icon", undefined] }, null, "$_id"] }
        }
      }
    }
  }},
  { "$unwind": "$data" },
  { "$replaceRoot": { "newRoot": "$data" }}
])
```

Comment: For the top layer, parent needs to be null. But I really like the use of map.

Comment: Indeed what I need..!

Answer (score 0):

This will do the trick:

The parent objects and child objects are separately processed as two facets. At the end, both results are combined into one array, which is then unwinded to give everything as separate documents.

```
db.collection.aggregate(
{
    "$unwind": {
        "path": "$children"
    },
},
{
    "$facet": {
        "parentObjs": [
            {
                "$group": {
                    "_id": "$_id",
                    "name": { "$first": "$name" }
                }
            },
            {
                "$addFields": { 
                    "parent": null 
                }
            }
        ],
        "childObjs": [
            {
                "$project": {
                    "_id": "$children._id",
                    "name": "$children.name",
                    "icon": "$children.icon",
                    "parent": "$_id"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
},
{
    "$project": { "items": { "$concatArrays": [ "$parentObjs", "$childObjs" ] } }
},
{
    "$unwind": {
        "path": "$items"
    }
}
)
```

Comment: Use `$replaceRoot` with `items`

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is this:

```
db.collection.aggregate({
    $addFields: {
        "children.parent": "$_id" // push the "_id" field into every array element
    }
}, {
    $addFields: {
        "children": { $concatArrays: [ "$children", [ { "_id": "$_id", "name": "$name", "parent": null } ] ] } // a the parent item into the "children" array
    }
}, {
    $unwind: "$children" // flatten the array
}, {
    $replaceRoot: {
        "newRoot": "$children" // move all content inside the "children" field to the top
    }
})
```